# Connect to Symbol MC70 with Windows 7

Tags: windows-mobile

I have spent(wasted) the past two hours googling for a solution.  Please help.  I am running Windows 7.  I have used VS2008 to build a mobile app, targeted at Windows Mobile 5.0 platform.  I need to deploy this app to a Symbol MC70 device (running Windows Mobile 5).  When I put the device in its cradle, and connect the cradle to my machine with a usb cable, the device shows up in "Devices and Printers" (in the "Unspecified" group) as "Symbol USB ActiveSync RNDIS".  When deploying my app from within VS2008, I select the "Windows Mobile 5 Pocket PC Device R2" option in the "Deploy Dispatch" dialog box.  The deploy fails with the following error: "The specified services does not exist as an installed service."  How do I get Windows 7 to correctly see the attached device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all else fails (and it seems it has) copy the CoreCon bits (conmanclient2, cmaccept, etc) to the device and manually run them.  [See this blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdteam/archive/2005/04/28/413304.aspx).

Comment: That would seem like the way to go, but the fact that windows cannot see the device leaves me with no way to actually copy files to the device...well actually the device can call a web service that is on my dev machine; and my dev machine can ping the device and the device can ping my dev machine...but in Windows I cannot open file explorer so as to browse the device's folders...any idea how I can do that?

Comment: It has no USB/SD card slot (I can't keep all of the handheld features straight)? Can the device hit a network share maybe?

Comment: ok I got the files to the device using dropbox...but my next question makes me feel like a dumbass...how do I open a command prompt on the device?

Comment: You have no file explorer?  They don't take params.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you haven't installed Windows Mobile Device Center. You can download it here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=46f72df1-e46a-4a5f-a791-09f07aaa1914

Comment: Sallow that actually raises another point about which I was planning on posting another question...I have WMDC installed, but it does not launch no matter how I try.  From the Start menu, by double-clicking on the exe (in c\windows\windowsmobile) and by using the command prompt to launch the exe with the /show command line parameter (something else I found during my hours of searching).  It just does not launch...I feel like crying...

Comment: Make sure you install the correct one. There is a 64-bit version as well: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=4F68EB56-7825-43B2-AC89-2030ED98ED95

Comment: Also make sure your WM settings on the MC70 under Settings, USB to PC , has the checkbox check for Enable advanced Network functionality.

Comment: @FredrikLjung this link provides WMDC for windows vista. Not for windows 7

Comment: That version works for Windows 7 as well. It even works on Windows 8 (fine for me but my work mate hade some weird issues on 8).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is a bit late down the line, but if anyone else has this problem, try the following:

Windows will provide the drivers, however it didn't do for me automatically.

Goto Device Manager and you should see the symbol device there in the unknown devices section. Right click and update the driver (allow it to search automatically) and let it do its thing.